# Azure DevOps On Premise Proxy Server

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

Can an **Azure DevOps proxy server** be used to facilitate artifact and pipeline releases for a DMZ environment (e.g containers).

For example,

> LAN Azure DevOps > Azure DevOps Proxy > Containers in DMZ

When I've looked at the proxy documentation it seems to just relate to artifact caching.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: So think I worked this out. Configure multiple application tiers, the DMZ servers connect to a particular application tier that is accessible to them and the LAN servers talk to the other application tier with a shared data tier between the two. The public URL would be a generic name (e.g. Azure DevOps) and then the DNS entries adjusted accordingly within zone to point at the appropriate application tier. If anyone can let me know whether this sounds reasonable, I did some testing and it seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use proxy server for that and connect it to particular port using firewall rules and telnet to see if connection is working fine.

We used to do same using the proxy server between artifact server and Azure DevOps server by opening some firewalls rules for particular port.

Comment: Thanks, so just to confirm I would be able to run the pipeline through the proxy server down to the agent?

Comment: Yes, as per my understanding, as i am not aware of your whole infrastructure and Configuration so cannot think much. But you can gave a try on this. make sure that proxy server have proper connectivity between Artifact server and Azure DevOps server.